# Facebook Like Button For Email

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-like, html-email

Ok, so I've looked around a number of different websites but seem to get mixed information. Does anyone have any advice for implementing a Facebook Like button in an HTML email campaign?

I have already tried this article but for some reason, clicking the like opens a blank page with another like button. http://emailexpert.org/adding-a-facebook-like-button-to-your-email-template/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how you can add a Facebook Like button, Share Button, and Tweet Buttons. Please Note: Where it says `my-campaign-url.com`  is the webpage of the email newsletter. Replace `img src` with your own image for the button. Also I am not sure you need everything in the Facebook button but you can clean it up with some testing =>

**Facebook Like**

```
<a title="Like this on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.
php?href=http://my-campaign-url.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=
false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=427%20">
<img src="/Images/network_icons/fblike-button-small.png" style="border: 
0 none;" alt="Like This on Facebook"></a>
```

**Facebook Share**

```
<a title="Share this on Facebook" href='http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://my-campaign-url.com'><img src='/Images/network_icons/fb-share.png' alt='Share my campaign' /></a>
```

**Tweet Button**

```
<a title="Share Via Twitter" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?
url=http://my-campaign-url&amp;text=My%20Text%20-%20&amp;via=My Name&amp;">
<img src="/Images/network_icons/tweet-button-small.png" 
style="border:0 none;" alt="Share Via Twitter"></a>
```

**Another (possibly easier) option.**

Use the AddThis Service for E-Mail Marketing. [See AddThis site for more info](https://www.addthis.com/get). Example Code Follows:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/facebook/offer?pco=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.com%2Fnewsletter&amp;pubid=ra-[Your AddThis ID for Analytics]" target="_blank" ><img src="http://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/facebook.png" border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a>
<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/twitter/offer?pco=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.com%2Fnewsletter&amp;pubid=ra-[Your AddThis ID for Analytics]" target="_blank" ><img src="http://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/twitter.png" border="0" alt="Twitter" /></a>
<!-- Rest of AddThis Services-->
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?source=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;=250&amp;pubid=ra-[Your AddThis ID for Analytics]&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-site.com%2Fnewsletter " target="_blank"  ><img src="http://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/more.png" border="0" alt="More..." /></a>
```

Comment: The 'facebook like' seems to be end in an empty page (blank page). Not supported anymore?

Comment: @Erwinus - I am unsure. I don't use Facebook Like in email anymore. I highly recommend AddThis for email newsletters, however, they only offer Facebook Share and not Facebook Like.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also.  But the answers above, and elsewhere, didn't help me too much.

It seemed like often the solution being offered was creating a way to allow people to like the EMAIL CAMPAIGN itself. That's definitely not what I want... I want it to make it so that people can click to like MY ORGANIZATION'S FACEBOOK PAGE.

Fortunately, I am a mailChimp user, and for those of you that use MailChimp, this is the article that explains it very easily:  http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-add-a-become-a-fan-on-facebook-button-to-my-campaigns

this allows you to simply put a special tag and to specify the URL of your FB page... awesome.  And it works. Sure, you do have to confirm with a second click, but that is OK.