# How to embed the facebook like button in the email template

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, html-email

Previously I have embed the facebook like button by using the following url.

```
<a href=
"http://www.facebook.com/plugin/like.php?href=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.prudentiallocations.com%252Fnews%252Finvestments%252Fhow-to-choose-investment property.aspx&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;color scheme=light&amp;height=427" >Like</a>
```

But, now it's not working, so can anybody tell me how we can use the facebook like functionality in the email

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Like Button For Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956657/facebook-like-button-for-email), + http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=like%20button%20email

Answer (score 0):

I think it still works, but your href has to start with: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php

You forgot the s after plugin